# Python pretty printing with GDB does not support map's indexing operator []

Tags: c++, gdb

I have in trouble in inspecting std::map type variable with GDB. In GDB, I usually use the pretty-printer in libstd-c++ repository (https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport) to print items in STL containers. The pretty-printer works fine with simple containers like vector, but it does not seem to fully support map.

To find an item with a given key in map, I tried to use operator[], but GDB reported the following error message, "Could not find operator[]".

Is it due to the pretty-printer's lack of support of map? or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pretty-printers are just a display feature.  They don't affect evaluation.  This can be confusing at times, as you've found.

In your case, gdb is trying to invoke the correct `operator[]`.  However, your compiler has optimized it away -- this is very common in C++ programs.

One option might be to compile with `-fkeep-inline-functions`.  This will cause an out-of-line copy to be emitted.  But, this isn't always desirable.

Another method might be to use gdb's relatively new `xmethod` feature ([see the relevant manual page](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Xmethods-In-Python.html)) to write your own.  Some xmethods for libstdc++ already went into the GCC tree, so your answer might be as simple as upgrading GCC.